# Remove Loading div on Iframe loaded Mootools

Tags: iframe, mootools

Am I missing something here?
http://jsfiddle.net/CMp3n/14/

I am trying to hide the loading div once iframe has loaded.

isn't addEvent listening on Iframes also or is there different event listener for Iframes in mootools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes we are just blind :)

```
  iframe.addEvent('load', function(){
      load.fade('out');
  });
```

does the trick just fine